# HTML Nav isn't working as expected

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the HTML `nav` tag for showing the breadcrumbs in my website (built on Django/Bootstrap).

I'm trying to show a dropdown menu for `Shop by Departments` and then the breadcrumbs. But someone, the order is mixed up. The `Shop by Departments` is showing up in the end instead of being the first thing.

My code is:

```
<div class="animate-dropdown">
<!-- ========================================= BREADCRUMB ========================================= --><div id="top-mega-nav">
<div class="container">
    <nav>
    {% include "partials/nav_primary.html" with expand_dropdown=0 %}
    <li class="breadcrumb-nav-holder">
        <ul>
        {% with category=product.categories.all.0 %}
            {% for c in category.get_ancestors_and_self %}
                <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                    <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
                </li><!-- /.breadcrumb-item -->
            {% endfor %}
            <li class="active">{{ product.title }}</li>
            {% get_back_button as backbutton %}
            {% if backbutton %}
                <li class="pull-right">
                    <a href="{{ backbutton.url }}">
                        <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> {{ backbutton.title }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

        </ul>
    </li><!-- /.breadcrumb-nav-holder -->
    </nav>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

I inspected the webpage using the inspector and the order of code is as expected. But the rendering is not. Whats wrong here?

Edit: The output in the inspector looks like
[image: web-inspector-output]

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Does the first `include` have an `ul` in it?

Comment: @putvande have updated the question w/the output.

Comment: So that is invalid HTML, since your `li class="breacrumb-nav-holder"` doesn't have the required parent `ul`.

Comment: Perfect. Add it as an answer for me to accept it? @putvande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rendered HTML is invalid. That is what likely causes the problems.
A `li` element must have a parent `ul` (or `ol`) element. 
So if you add an `ul` around your `li class="breacrumb-nav-holder"` it should work fine.